# Tengo un problema con PHPMailer, no responde ni hace nada

Tags: php, formularios, phpmailer, gmail

Tengo problemas con mi PHPMailer a gmail, tengo activada la verificación a dos pasos, la contraseña de aplicación que me da gmail, la cual he elegido en seleccionar aplicación: **OTRA** pero no funciona, no me envía correo, puede ser por **gmail** o debería de usar **outlook**, he mirado videos y ya la única opción que me queda sois vosotros:

[image: Contraseña aplicación]

**Este es mi php "enviarcontacto.php":**

```
<?php
$nombre = $_POST["name"];
$correo = $_POST["email"];
$asunto = $_POST["subject"];
$mensaje = $_POST["message"];
//Contenido correo

$body = "Nombre: " . $nombre . "<br>Correo: " . $correo . "<br>Mensaje: " . $mensaje;
//Importar clases PHPMailer
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

//Dirección de ficheros zip
require './PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require './PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require './PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

//Crear estancia
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Ajustes server
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                       //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'micorreo@gmail.com';               //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'sijanaisncascsjna';                     //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Activar autenticacion smtp servidor
    $mail->Port       = 587;  //o 465                           //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom($correo, $nombre);
    $mail->addAddress('micorreo@gmail.com');                                 //Add a recipient(A QUIEN SE ENVIA CORREO)

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';                                //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $asunto;
    $mail->Body    = $body;

    //Enviar
    $mail->send();
    echo "<script language='javascript'>
    alert('¡¡¡Correo enviado con éxito!!!');
    window.location.replace('./inicio_sesión.php');
    </script>";
    exit;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "¡¡¡Correo no enviado: $mail->ErrorInfo!!!";
}
 ?>
```

**Y así tengo el form.html:**

```
<form class="contact-form" form="enviarcontacto.php" method="post">
            <h2>Contáctanos</h2>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Escriba aquí su nombre completo..." required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Correo electrónico</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Escriba aquí su email..." required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subject">Asunto</label>
                <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Escriba aquí su asunto..." required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message">Mensaje</label>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="4" placeholder="Escriba aquí su mensaje..." required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="botones">
                <input type="submit" name="comprobar" value="Enviar">
            </div>
        </form>
```

He probado con otros tipos de scripts en javascript otros php, y pasaba en todos lo mismo, no hacen nada, si hago un alert no lo hace, ¿Qué puede ser?.

-Gracias de antemano

Comment: El código se encuentra dentro de una `function email()`, pero ¿dónde llamas a esa función? No lo veo por ninguna parte.

Comment: añadiendo al comentario de @A.Cedano, me parece que a tu `function email()` le tendrías también que pasar los parámetros `$_POST[]` y el `$body`, o en su defecto y dependiendo de la futura lógica, comenta la `function email(){}` y deja todo "plano".

Comment: Se me olvidó pasar el código correcto, estuve probando distintas funciones y al ver que no me funcionaba fui simplificando el código, pero tampoco responde.

Comment: Pienso que puede ser por usar smtp.gmail.

Comment: Y ¿cuál es el código que estás usando realmente? Pulsa en [edit] y agrégalo. Además PHPMailer tiene opción de depuración que podrías implementar para saber con exactitud lo que está fallando.

Comment: Simplemente quito el function email(), así es el código que proporciona phpmailer, y he visto varios videos y foros, lo tengo igual que ellos pero no se donde puede estar el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta intentando utilizar un puerto que requiere TLS.

Si quieres utilizar  el puerto 587 de smtp debes utilizar TLS , pero no lo esta especificando:

Si desea utilizar TLS cambie la  variable SMTPSecure:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Activar autenticacion smtp servidor
$mail->Port       = 587;                           //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`
```

O si no requieres TLS envíelo por el puerto correspondiente

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Activar autenticacion smtp servidor
$mail->Port       = 465;                           //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`
```

Comment: Así es, ese era mi problema, aún así he probado con outlook y da menos problema y es más fácil. Si a alguien le interesa, con el mismo puerto(587), con $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS; y 'smtp-mail.outlook.com'. Os lo debería de servir para los de outlook